# Show package version in SublimeText

Tags: version, sublimetext3, sublimetext

This seems like a simple enough task but I couldn't find a way to do this.

I need to know the version of an installed package (to add as information on an issue I'm opening) but there's apparently no way to do this.

Did I miss something?

I'm running SublimeText 3103.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the Command Palette
2. Type `PC: list` and select `Package Control - List Packages`
3. Find the package you want, you will see the version number next to the URL of the package

[image: List Packages]

Comment: That was easy enough (although not very convenient), thank you!